# In Asterisk how can I use originate command to send a fax with Elastix virtual fax

Tags: asterisk, voip, elastix

I want to send a fax with my application via Asterisk. I need to execute Originate command to send a fax and use Elastix virtual fax.
My Elastix virtual fax is defined IAX and 999 extension number.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: Thanks, I was previously work with cards, for this case there is no card and so there is no DAHDI channel. This code was worked correctrly :
http://172.16.1.19:8088/rawman?Action=Originate&Context=crm_sendfax&Priority=1&Channel=DAHDI/g0/909000000001&Exten=s&Variable=InputFileName=72.tif

172.16.1.19 = Elastix IP address.
Context=crm_sendfax is a context I define in extension_custom.conf

Answer (score 0):

Commandline:

```
asterisk -rx "channel originate Local/1234567890@from-internal extension 999@from-internal"
```

> pro-sip*CLI> channel originate (tab pressed)
>   There are two ways to use this
>   command. A call can be originated between a channel and a specific
>   application, or between a channel and an extension in the dialplan.
>   This is similar to call files or the manager originate action. Calls
>   originated with this command are given a timeout of 30 seconds.
>
> Usage1: channel originate  application  [appdata] 
>   This will originate a call between the specified channel tech/data and
>   the given application. Arguments to the application are optional. If
>   the given arguments to the application include spaces, all of the
>   arguments to the application need to be placed in quotation marks.
>
> Usage2: channel originate  extension [exten@][context]
>   This will originate a call between the specified channel tech/data and
>   the given extension. If no context is specified, the 'default' context
>   will be used. If no extension is given, the 's' extension will be
>   used.

Sure this example not check anything like channel not availible or busy etc.

You can do same using AMI action originate

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+Originate

Correct application should also check dialling state, redial etc.